# ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed - Error in flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-render

When i try to add this package [pdf_render: ^1.0.12](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_render), i got these two error's

> Execution failed for task ':pdf_render:externalNativeBuildDebug'.

> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

I reinstalled the ndk. And my flutter doctor says No issues found!

How can i solve this issue?